# BIRT CELL CONDITIONAL HIGHLIGHTING

Tags: javascript, reporting, birt

I need to color some rows in a report table with BIRT.
There is already something similar discussed but it is not enough for me.

What I would like to do is color the cells like Excel does with its conditional formatting i.e I have several rows and I want to color them acoording to its “intensity”. For example, r1= 10, r2= 20, r3= 100. I would see r3 with the most saturated color and r1 with the least.

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Javascript inside the onCreate event.
Probably better for the data item itself, not for the cell containing the item.

At least this is easy with table items, but it seems you are using a cross tab.
The following guide is for TABLEs:
You can access the value with the ususal row["NAME"] syntax in the onCreate event, even though the palette does not offer it.
So, for example (untested):

```
var cell_value = row["NAME"];
var intensity = do_something_to_compute_this_from(cell_value);
// should be in the range 0.0 to 1.0
// Now compute RGB values from a "base" RGB ( 0 .. 255 )
var white = [255, 255, 255];
var base = [ 0, 60, 0 ]; // some green
var result = [];
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    var w = white[i];
    var b = base[i];
    var r = int( intensity * b + (1-intensity) * w ); 
    result.push(r);
}
this.getStyle().backgroundColor = "RGB(" + result[0] + "," + result[1] + "," + result[2] + ")";
```

Comment: For context: I am using KNIME to organize the data and BIRT for the reporting. It is not, in fact, a crosstab. The original data table contains almost the same information (withouth a couple of filters that I applied in the table). 
Besides, I do not have almost any experience with BIRT and I do not know anything about Javascript... but I can try. How can I modify the "onCreat" event?

Comment: Click on the cell or the data item in the layout, then open the Script tab instead of the Layout, then select the onCreate event. Since BIRT doesn't support your value-based-intensity feature, you'll need a little scripting knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Conditional Formatting associated with the Highlight feature?

You would click on the cell where you want the conditional formatting.
Click on the highlights tab
Click on Add
Set up your condition
Set up your preferred format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvj6R.png). I tried sending a screenshot of the screen where the conditional formatting is set up, but I guess I'm too new to this format.  Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: This does not offer comparison between columns, it only allows for formatting one column (with its own values) at a time.